# "message":Unauthorized(access token cannot be refreshed in absense of refresh token----while hitting the service from kong api gateway

Tags: openid-connect, kong

I am using OpenID connect plugin for Kong api gateway. I have been struggling to configure it.

When i am trying to hit the service----e.g (from domain a to domain b) through Kong. i am getting this error **"message":Unauthorized(access token cannot be refreshed in absense of refresh token **
May I know what reason will get this kind off error.

message":Unauthorized(access token cannot be refreshed in absense of refresh token

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.